# How do I view "newest questions" when they don't show up?

Tags: support

Sometimes when I click on the "Questions" tab, I get brought up with a big list which either has locked on "newest" or "interesting" as a sub-tab. If the locked tab is "interesting", I can't find the newest questions tab. Does anyone know how to do that, or what I'm doing wrong?

If I'm not making any sense, please tell me.

Comment: click "Questions" button.  To get back click the site logo to the left of the question button

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks. It seems I was getting confused by two completely different panels.

Comment: I agree that this is confusing. I understand that the owners of the site might be trying to optimize for something different with the home page, but the pages are so similar, my brain thought they were the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base assumption is wrong, you will never see "interesting" when clicking the "Questions" top link. "interesting" tab is unique to Stack Overflow and appears only when  you are in its very [home page](https://stackoverflow.com/), not in the [Questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) itself.

So you see "interesting" tab when getting to the homepage, e.g. clicking the logo.

Nothing is locked, to see questions sorted by "newest" i.e. time of asking, go to the Questions page where you have such a tab.

Bottom line, the home page/landing page and the Questions page are two different views, that is the reason for different tabs.